# is there an instruction manual for ubuntu 16.04.2?

Tags: documentation

Is there a book or instruction manual for ubuntu 16.04.2, other than the ubuntu desktop guide, that has all the commands for the terminal with definitions and uses for each one clearly defined?

Answer (score 0):

Trust me you can get all the necessary help you need from the Ubuntu documentation.

https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/ubuntu-help/index.html

It was of tremendous help for me while getting used to Ubuntu you can also get some help of some basic commands from the link below;

http://ecourts.nic.in/2/mannual/admin_manual.pdf

I hope these should be of assistance to you.

Answer (score 0):

http://tldp.org/

Q: What is LDP?

A: LDP is a loosely knit team of volunteers who provide documentation for many aspects of Linux. There are several forms of documentation: Guides, HOWTOs, man pages, and FAQs.

http://linuxcommand.org/tlcl.php/

creative commons licensed book for learning the Bourne Again SHell (bash)

open up a terminal and type in at the prompt

```
$ man man
```